# How to E2E test functionality of Storm Topology by programmatically inserting messages

Tags: apache-storm, apache-storm-topology

Our Apache Storm topology listens messages from Kafka using KafkaSpout and after doing lot of mapping/reducing/enrichment/aggregation etc. etc finally inserts data into Cassandra. There is another kafka input where we receive user queries for data if topology finds a response then it sends that onto a third kafka topic. Now we want to write E2E test using Junit in which we can directly programmatically insert data into topology and then by inserting user query message, we can assert on third point that response received on our query is correct.

To achieve this, we thought of starting EmbeddedKafka and CassandraUnit and then replacing actual Kafka and  Cassandra with them and then we can start topology in the context of this single Junit test.

But our approach doesn't fit well with JUnit because it makes these tests too bulky. Starting kafka, cassandra and topology all are time taking and consume lot of resource. Is there anything in Apache Storm which can support kind of testing we are planning to write?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of options you have here, depending on what kind of slowdown you can live with:

- As you mentioned, you can start Kafka, Cassandra and the topology. This is the slowest option, and the "most realistic".
- Start Kafka and Cassandra once, and reuse them for all the tests. You can do the same with the Storm LocalCluster. It is likely faster to clear Kafka/Cassandra between each test (e.g. deleting all topics) instead of restarting them.
- Replace the Kafka spouts/bolts and Cassandra bolt with stubs in test. Storm has a number of tools built in for stubbing bolts and spouts, e.g. the FixedTupleSpout, FeederSpout, the tracked topology and completable topology functionality in LocalCluster. This way you can insert some fixed tuples into the topology, and do asserts about which tuples where sent to the Cassandra bolt stub. There's examples of some of this functionality [here](https://github.com/apache/storm/blob/e0feb6cf04107029d4b24420f265495cdfbdb098/storm-server/src/test/java/org/apache/storm/TestingTest.java) and [here](https://github.com/apache/storm/blob/8f49e06998abb4dfc50f51d78b6784ebd04844fb/storm-core/test/jvm/org/apache/storm/integration/TestingTest.java)
- Finally you can of course unit test individual bolts. This is the fastest kind of test. You can use Testing.testTuple to create test tuples to pass to the bolt.

Comment: Thanks for answer. Is there any Java API, which can tell us when Topology is ready for execution? Because before start of test I am submitting my topology and before it gets ready for execution my test execution finishes up and fails. I need a Java API which can help me wait until topology is ready.

Comment: Please post another question, that way other people can find it when they have the same question.

Comment: Asked that question here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57172246/is-there-any-java-api-to-know-when-topology-is-ready-for-processing

Comment: I tried your suggestions but facing one issue. Posting a new question here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57244911/what-can-be-used-as-a-test-stub-for-cassandrawriterbolt