# Is there any Java API to know when topology is ready for reading first message from Spout

Tags: apache-storm, apache-storm-topology

Our Apache Storm topology listens messages from Kafka using KafkaSpout and after doing lot of mapping/reducing/enrichment/aggregation etc. etc finally inserts data into Cassandra. There is another kafka input where we receive user queries for data if topology finds a response then it sends that onto a third kafka topic. Now we want to write E2E test using Junit in which we can directly programmatically insert data into topology and then by inserting user query message, we can assert on third point that response received on our query is correct.

To achieve this, we thought of starting EmbeddedKafka and CassandraUnit and then replacing actual Kafka and Cassandra with them and then we can start topology in the context of this single Junit test.

Before, we start our actual test, we create topology and submit it into LocalCluster. It starts topology on a different thread and comes out from Before and starts executing our test. Till that time, topology is not ready because it takes some time to be ready for processing. Is there any java API which can tell us when topology is ready for processing (means ready to read first message from Spout)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This depends on what you mean when you say "ready for processing".

If you enable time simulation for your LocalCluster, you can use `Time.advanceClusterTime` to advance time in steps. If you call this method after submitting a topology, it will only return once the cluster is mostly idling. See e.g. https://github.com/apache/storm/blob/8f49e06998abb4dfc50f51d78b6784ebd04844fb/storm-core/test/jvm/org/apache/storm/integration/TopologyIntegrationTest.java#L233.

If you're willing to replace your spouts with stubs (e.g. FixedTupleSpout), you can use `Testing.completeTopology`to wait until the topology has finished processing all the tuples you set up the stub to emit.

Another method to wait for the topology to have processed some tuples would be that you put some messages in Kafka, start your topology, and then have your testing thread poll Cassandra to see if the messages you expect have made it through. This way, you can set a timeout in your testing thread, and have the test fail if the condition is not met in some number of seconds. You could use a utility like Awaitility for this https://github.com/awaitility/awaitility, or just write your own polling logic.

If you mean something else by "ready for processing", please describe in more detail what you mean.

Comment: 'Ready for processing' means ready to read first message from Spout.

Comment: Do we have any blog or book on Storm testing? Based on your answers, now I know there are many test helper classes in test package and Testing.java is full of many things which can be used for Storm topology testing.Is there any online resource which can explain the usage of all the classes present in testing package + Testing.java?

Comment: I don't believe so. Various people have written about this over the years, I think https://github.com/xumingming/storm-lib/blob/master/src/jvm/storm/TestingApiDemo.java is the closest to a full overview. It might be good to add a section on this to the website https://github.com/apache/storm/blob/master/DEVELOPER.md#contribute-documentation

Comment: any reason for downgrading it?

Comment: Downgrading what?

Comment: I mean why this question was down voted? I started writing a doc on testing Storm topology end to end. Need your help in that. Will send you the link for review. Once approved by you, same can be part of Storm documentation.

Comment: I don't know why it was downvoted. Sounds good, if possible please open a PR against https://github.com/apache/storm, that way other maintainers can also review.

Comment: Thanks for your comments and supports. I forked storm repo in github. Created a module storm-cassandra-examples under example. Create a topology to process eCommerce related events, will read them from Kafka and will store them in Cassandra in the raw form as well as some aggregated data. Then will end to end test this topology. Then will write document related to end to end testing of storm topology and will give reference from storm-cassandra-examples module. Does this sound good? Is there any other communication channel to talk to you other than this stackoverflow?

Comment: That sounds fine. We already have some end to end testing examples (e.g. the various tests marked @IntegrationTest), but having an example for Cassandra would be fine too. If you want to propose changes or get feedback, consider using the storm-dev mailing list (https://storm.apache.org/getting-help.html). I read that list, as do a bunch of other Storm developers.

Comment: While writing an example for Storm, Cassandra and kafka, found some of the classes are using shaded classes, for example - ConfigUtils class is using org.apache.storm.shade.com.google.common.collect.Maps.

In my InteliiJ setup, ConfigUtils is unable to find this import.

I have run mvn clean install which was executed successfully and saw apache-storm-shaded jar was created. Even I looked inside that jar and all the referred classes are part of this jar.

how to fix this issue because I am unable to run my tests, these are failing on these compilations errors in other classes?

Comment: There's a bug in IntelliJ somewhere that causes it to fail to find the shaded classes. We've worked around it with a Maven profile, you should be able to enable it in your IntelliJ settings https://github.com/apache/storm/blob/7bc48361531027d078842e3cec00eae6945d22fa/pom.xml#L379

Comment: I activated IntelliJ maven profile. Still, it didn't help. Am I missing anything? [Sent an email to developer group email, with screenshot]

Comment: Sir, any help on that profile related issue. I am done with my code changes, unable to test my changes. If this issue is fixed, I can test and create a pull request.

Comment: Ethan posted a link to another workaround here http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/storm-dev/201908.mbox/browser. Please try that.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I saw that provided URL, it has a very long mail trail. I read every mail sent by Ethen but unfortunately couldn't find the answer I was looking for. I know I am becoming too much of burden on you however I think it is just an initial glitch once I am through this I will try my best to have a great journey with Storm. I'll request if you can please provide me the link you were talking about.

Comment: Whoops, sorry. I meant to link to the post, not the whole archive. http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/storm-dev/201908.mbox/%3C73A92005-B970-4B3B-AC6E-1F07F15F3ED7%40gmail.com%3E